# Jmeter: "No certificate found for alias"

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate, keystore, client-certificates

I'm having a problem trying to get a client-side certificate loaded using Jmeter. I believe I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/docs/how-to-test-your-apis/how-to-configure-jmeter-to-use-client-side-ssl/), but am getting an error when running my tests.

From what I can tell, it seems like my keystore file is set up correctly. If I run `keytool -list -v -keystore <mykeystore>` I get:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: client
Creation date: Jul 31, 2017
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
<certificate body>
```

When I run my tests, things seem to be running okay from the beginning

```
Total of 1 aliases loaded OK from keystore
```

However, in the results output I see the error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No certificate found for alias:'client'
```

What could be causing Jmeter to fail reading the certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For non-telepathic JMeter experts it will be quite hard to provide the answer without knowing your exact configuration steps so I will just come up with a solution that definitely works:

1. Revert all your configuration changes (or just get a clean JMeter from [downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. Add the next lines to *system.properties* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 or jks  
   javax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/your/jks keystore or .p12 certificate
   javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=your certificate or keystore password
   ```
3. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up (if you pass the properties via -D command-line argument like `jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=secret.p12 ...` - restart will not be required)

That's it, now your outgoing HTTP Requests will be encrypted using the certificate provided.

More information:

- [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)
- [Specify the keystore of certificates using the javax.net.ssl.keyStore system property](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SpecifythekeystoreofcertificatesusingthejavaxnetsslkeyStoresystemproperty.htm)

Comment: This was helpful, thank you. That did solve the issue of not being able to find alias. It's now moved on to an error in regards to the server cert, `Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException,Non HTTP response message: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca` but that might be a different issue altogether.

Comment: You probably need to setup the trustStore too:

javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path to PKCS12 or JKS truststore file>
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<truststore password here>
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=<pkcs12 | jks>